# Font Awesome not displaying in Chrome on Android

Tags: android, wordpress, google-chrome

I've setup a WordPress website using Avada theme (6.0.3). I'm using Font Awesome in the site.

I now find that, using a Google Pixel 3 mobile phone with Android 9 operating system and Chrome 78, the Font Awesome icons do not display.

I've trawled the web and Stack Overflow looking for answers. There are a few documented problems (going back to 2018 and earlier) with previous versions of Chrome but no solutions that work for me.

Just wondering if (as at Nov. 2019) this is still a known problem with FA/Chrome? If so, are there any possible solutions?

Thanks,

Mekong

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like it was a Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) problem.

Pasting the code below into .htaccess file solved the issue:

```
# Allow access from all domains for webfonts.
# Alternatively you could only whitelist your
# subdomains like "subdomain.example.com".
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css)$">
       Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and adding how you solved the problem. That saved my day today a couple of years later :)

Comment: No worries. Glad I was able to help. Thanks for your comment.